# Can you append a string and a number as a single entry to a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, integer, append

Is there a way in python 3 to append, to a list, both a string and a number as a single entry.
For example if I had a list of class names, and wanted to be able to sort the list alphabetically, I would use:

```
classNames = []
classNames.sort()
print(classNames)
```

This would produce something like the following once names were appended:

```
["Adam", "Ben", "Charlotte"]
```

But if I wanted to be able to assign a score for a test such to produce:

```
["Adam" 12/15, "Ben" 9/15, "Charlotte" 14/15]
```

Would this be possible? Can I do it using lists or do I have to use other more complicated syntax?

Comment: List of list. Or list of tuple.

Comment: `12/15` will work fine. You just have to multiply by 15 when you want the original raw score.

Comment: I don't know why its all a block text sorry if that makes it hard to understand, I did actually have separate lines for my code

Comment: If the values are related, a list of dictionaries might be prefered: `[{ name: "Adam" date: "12/15"}, {name: "Ben", date: "9/15"}]`

Comment: The `9/15` is a score, not a date.

Comment: If needed, you might use [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) to store rational numbers

Comment: Question:  do you consider `12/15`, 19/15`, `14/15` to be numbers?  Do you want to do a division?  If they are numbers then are they integers or floating point?  If they are not numbers, then what are they?

Comment: the 12/15 etc are scores for the test. Though this question has been resolved its worth noting that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can insert a tuple containing the elements you want.

```
a=[]
a.append(("Test",(12,15)))
```

then `a[0][0]` will be equal to "Test", `a[0][1][0]` will be `12` and `a[0][1][1]` will be `15`.

To my mind, you don't need that `12/15` business.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [fractions library](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fractions.html) therefore you can structure your data like so:

```
 [("John", Fraction(5,12)), ("Alice", Fraction(8, 13))]
```

As it has been pointed out you can also use a named tuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from fractions import Fraction
StudentScore = namedtuple('StudentScore', ['name', 'score'])
x = StudentScore('John', Fraction(5, 12))


In [109]: x.name
Out[109]: 'John'

In [110]: x.score
Out[110]: Fraction(5, 12)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `tuple`:

```
data = [("Adam",12/15), ("Ben",9/15), ("Charlotte",14/15)] 
data.append(("new name", new_numerator/new_denominator))
```

Or you could store the numerator and the denominator separately:

```
data = [( "Adam",(12,15) ), ( "Ben",(9,15) ), ( "Charlotte",(14,15) )] 
data.append(("new name", (new_numerator,new_denominator)))
```

You could also fore go the `list` and just use a `dict`:

```
data = {
     "Adam":(12,15),
     "Ben":(9,15),
     "Charlotte":(14,15)
}
data["new name"] = (new_numerator,new_denominator)
```

**EDIT:**

After consideration of my discussion in the comments with **@TigerhawkT3**.  Though based on an assumption, I felt he had a good point.

If your denominator is a constant across all your data it would be better to store it once in some variable and only score the number of questions answered correctly by each student:

```
number_of_questions = 15
data = [( "Adam",12 ), ( "Ben",9 ), ( "Charlotte",14 )] 
data.append(("new name", (new_numerator,new_denominator)))
```

or as a `dict`

```
number_of_questions = 15
data = {
     "Adam":12,
     "Ben":9,
     "Charlotte":14
}
data["new name"] = new_score
```

Comment: still gonna give you not expected output

Comment: 9/15 === 0 ; 12/15 === 0 ; 14/15 === 0

Comment: The original post did specify Python 3.

Comment: ok now it is mostly correct ... removed my downvote :) (in fact it is now an upvote :) )

Comment: I don't see any reason to store the maximum score multiple times.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That would be assuming there could not be data with different maximum scores.

Comment: The question doesn't indicate a variety of maximum scores. At the very least, store a maximum score separately and then include it in the score list by reference, to conform to DRY. I'm sure you can see the potential problem if the teacher decides to remove an unclear question and make the maximum score `14`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  The question does not address in either direction what the possible values for the denominator could be, so anything would an assumption that I don't feel is necessary.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What if these tests are not the same tests and coincidentally have the same number of questions?  What if they want to store multiple tests in the same data set?  What if they handout an extra credit question and the number bumps to 16?  There are any number of special cases we could factor in, however, the question here is how to store the presented data, not how to design a system for storing test scores.  If you want to present an alternative where you store the denominator once, go ahead, I won't stop you.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 To be clear, I am not disagreeing with the fact that **If** the denominator is constant across all test score data, that it would be better to store it once.  I think you are right.  I am saying that it was not part of the question and since no indication was made towards either direction we would only be assuming until we asked OP.